# How do I return an array with a unique key?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have this JSON.

[{"transaction_code":"NKO27E93OU","transaction_timestamp":"20191124215327","transaction_date":"24-Nov-2019","transaction_time":"09:53 PM","transaction_amount":"1.00","transaction_account":"1235688jose","transactor_number":"254704476967","transactor_fname":"JOSPHAT","transactor_mname":"GITIRA","transactor_lname":""},{"transaction_code":"NL20DG5S4E","transaction_timestamp":"20191202124826","transaction_date":"02-Dec-2019","transaction_time":"12:48 PM","transaction_amount":"10.00","transaction_account":"s84d","transactor_number":"254704476967","transactor_fname":"JOSPHAT","transactor_mname":"GITIRA","transactor_lname":""}]

I want to return a unique array with a specific transaction code. Say if transaction code is NL20DG5S4E, then return the whole array. For now I can only access elements using this code.

```
      $pc = json_decode($paymentdata, true);


    // foreach($pc as $p){
    //     echo $p['transaction_code'].'\n';
    // }

    $array = $pc[6]['transaction_code'];
    return $array;
```

Comment: You could create a filter callback for `array_filter()` by the value you require. You could do the foreach and break once a match is found. You could create a function that performs this with the array as the first paramter and the data to locate as the second parameter

Comment: **Side note:** Why the Laravel tag?

Comment: @vivek_23 am using Laravel

Comment: @davidkihara Fine but you should usually use a tag if that tag has some relevancy in your question. The goal you want to achieve is easy possibly through PHP itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `array_filter` to solve this.

```
$pc = json_decode($array, true);

$result = array_filter($pc, function ($transaction) {
    return $transaction['transaction_code'] === 'NKO27E93OU';
});

echo $result[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a simple foreach loop to loop through your data and return the array once the transaction value is found.

```
<?php

$paymentdata = '[{"transaction_code":"NKO27E93OU","transaction_timestamp":"20191124215327","transaction_date":"24-Nov-2019","transaction_time":"09:53 PM","transaction_amount":"1.00","transaction_account":"1235688jose","transactor_number":"254704476967","transactor_fname":"JOSPHAT","transactor_mname":"GITIRA","transactor_lname":""},{"transaction_code":"NL20DG5S4E","transaction_timestamp":"20191202124826","transaction_date":"02-Dec-2019","transaction_time":"12:48 PM","transaction_amount":"10.00","transaction_account":"s84d","transactor_number":"254704476967","transactor_fname":"JOSPHAT","transactor_mname":"GITIRA","transactor_lname":""}]';


$pc = json_decode($paymentdata, true);

function returnAllInfo($pc,$transaction_code){
    foreach($pc as $data){
        if($data['transaction_code'] === $transaction_code) return $data;
    }
    return [];
}

print_r(returnAllInfo($pc,'NL20DG5S4E'));
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/iVcb4

Answer (score 3):

Direct access via key "NL20DG5S4E" is possible if [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) is used.

```
$pc = json_decode($paymentdata, true);

$arrTrCode = array_column($pc,null,'transaction_code')['NL20DG5S4E'];

/* or
$arrWithKeys = array_column($pc,null,'transaction_code');
$arrTrCode = $arrWithKeys['NL20DG5S4E'];
*/

echo '<pre>';
var_export($arrTrCode);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'transaction_code' => 'NL20DG5S4E',
  'transaction_timestamp' => '20191202124826',
  'transaction_date' => '02-Dec-2019',
  'transaction_time' => '12:48 PM',
  'transaction_amount' => '10.00',
  'transaction_account' => 's84d',
  'transactor_number' => '254704476967',
  'transactor_fname' => 'JOSPHAT',
  'transactor_mname' => 'GITIRA',
  'transactor_lname' => '',
)
```

Comment: $arrTrCode = array_column($pc,null,'transaction_code')['NL20DG5S4E'] Can I use this transaction code as a variable?

Comment: Do not understand your question correctly. $arrTrCode is a variable containing an array. How you name the variable is up to you. I do not think $array is good. The name should refer to the content of the variable. See also the update above with the alternative code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_filter` method to check the value of your specific key like:

```
$pc = json_decode($paymentdata, true);
$code = 'NL20DG5S4E';
$result = array_filter($pc, function($val) use($code){
   return $val['transaction_code'] == $code;
});
```

Or if you are using `laravel >= 5.5` then you can get it easily using `collection`

```
$pc = json_decode($paymentdata, true);

$collection = collect($pc);

$result = $collection->firstWhere('transaction_code', $code);
```

here is the [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-first-where)

Answer (score 0):

Below piece of code can help you with what you are looking.

```
<?php 
$pc = json_decode($paymentdata, true);

$arr = [];
foreach($pc as $key => $val)
{
  $arr[$val]['transaction_code'] = $val;
}

return $arr;
?>
```